# How can I convert web layout to print layout without disturbing the images?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, google-docs

I am using Word 2010 version.
I have word file in which I copied content from web page.
I choose web view it is fine. 
I tried to change the view of this document to print layout.

**The problem is that few image are getting cut when I do that.
and If I change the size of these images. It is getting blurred.
What should I do?**

For example if you copy this page https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-install-python
And it in word>Print layout
few images will get cut ?
It is fine in web layout.
Screenshot 1
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]
Screenshot 3
[image]

**I have already disabled my ruler(View>Show>Ruler) unchecked**
Image in landscape mode(Page layout>Page Setup>Orientation>landscape)
As you can see both images right side is getting cut. If I change its size the image is getting blurred. The only solution I could find was View>web view()

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to super user. Could you please post screenshots of how exactly your content is being cut? Did you copy the whole web page or simply individual sections?

Comment: Yeah sure@NatsuKage

Comment: It seems like your page layout is cutting off the pictures. If you change your page type (letter, Legal, etc.) does the cutting change?

Comment: @dennis try using landscape without wordwrap.

Comment: Some images are still not visible completly. Image 3. And if i change the width of image its getting blurred. @vssher

Comment: I would try editing the images a little (trimming off the sides, removing the white blanks). Make sure you are not set to use the ruler. With Windows Paint you could modify the images and bring #3 photo the data field to the left.

Comment: How can I not use the ruler? @vssher

Comment: Try this page, it may help https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001352.htm

Comment: Ruler was already disabled I checked @vssher

Answer (score 0):

Could you trim it a little like this? 
[image]